# Transitive verbs without direct objects

Tags: transitive-verbs, direct-objects

My linguistics teacher said the sentence "She put the book on the table." is wrong without 'on the table' part. I disagree with him.
Isn't in a sense transitive verbs also intransitive when you speak lazily or to the point, if you will? Some examples:
He killed him. -Who killed him? +Bob killed.
Some guy goes to jail and someone asks him: What did you do to end up here? + I killed, I robbed, I raped.
And I don't care about some prescriptive grammar rule. I am just interested if some native person would say these. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your teacher is right. The PP "on the table" is an obligatory complement of "put". You may well hear your other examples "I killed" etc., but syntactically they are intransitive. A clause is transitive only if it contains a direct object.

Comment: What would it mean to say _She put the book_ -- in what contexts could it be meaningful? It isn't an answer to _What did she do with the book?_ It isn't an answer to _Where is the book?_ It turns out that with _put_, the meaning is simply to move something to some place, and the place must be specified, otherwise there's no useful communication. This is not true with every verb of position and motion; _She moved the book_ is just fine without any locative. Every English verb has dozens of such restrictions, requirements, and affordances, and they all vary considerably. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your linguistics teacher is right.

""She put the book on the table." is wrong without 'on the table' part."

"She put the book."

Where? In the refrigerator? In the ocean? A bookshelf? Her backpack? The ground? Into orbit?

There are practically an infinite amount of places she could put the book, and without knowing where she put it, it is not a complete thought. If it is not a complete thought, it isn't a complete sentence.

"Some examples: He killed him."

This only works in a visual medium like a comic book or movie\tv show, or even real life and would involve pointing to emphasize who exactly "he" and "him" are.

"-Who killed him?"

This also requires further explanation either visually or in explaining sentences either before or after, or even both in a book or story.

"+Bob killed. Some guy goes to jail and someone asks him: What did you do to end up here? + I killed, I robbed, I raped."

This is a perfect example of what I mean, you set it up with Bob, then add in someone talking to Bob, as well as a setting, and have him ask a question; the question is then succinctly, but not completely answered by Bob. It is a prime example of what I tried to say before.

Comment: this is interesting.  i was pondering the same.  what if you don't know where she put the book or don't want to convey it.

Comment: thats an interesting question, i THINK that, in that case the best scenario would be to turn it into a question

as in
"Where did she put the book?"

or possibly a statement of fact?
"I have no idea where she put the book."

but if you didn't want to convey either way, you would have to be more....."iffy" in your wording, which would also translate into making it a question usually, 
as in
"Why would i know where she put the book?"
or even
"How could i possibly know where she put the book?"

Comment: well what if you don't care and don't know where she put the book.  you just want to convey the message that she really did put the book.  i guess you can say "she put the book somewhere", but it seems unnecessarily wordy just to conform to put being transitive.

Comment: not at all "put the book" or "she put the book" all alone, just doesn't make sense. you have to modify it by telling where, like "where she put the book, no one knows." .......basically if you wanna say something along the lines of, "she put the book", and actually have it make sense, you need to be speaking a language that isn't english.... she could throw it, if "in a mad rage, she threw the book blindly" it would satisfy the goal of not knowing where it went or is, and if you HAD to you could say it as simply as "she threw the book" and it would actually make sense.

Answer (score 0):

(I'll still add an answer after all this time because I don't find the other answers satisfying.)

Indeed the sentence is not acceptable but that is because the verb is not ‘put’ but the prepositional verb ‘put on’ where the ‘on’ is an unremovable part of the verb.

It is not about some pragmatic constraints but with ‘put on’ — quite like ‘put out’, ‘put away’, ‘put under’, ‘put through’, ‘put off’, ‘put in’, etc. — the ‘on’ is necessary to construct the meaning and the preposition is obligatory.

If you used another verb like ‘leave’ instead, it would have worked: “she left it on the table” vs “she left it”.

That you can't get rid of the preposition can best be seen in imperatives: “Put it on!”, “Put it away!” However in this case the the imperative “Put it on!” can't be used since it changes the meaning to ‘putting on clothes’ etc.